# Find number of solutions $ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7 = 7 $ where $x_i \in \left\{ 0,1,2 \right\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find number of solutions 
$$ x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7 = 7 \text{ such that } \forall_i x_i \in \left\{0,1,2\right\}$$
I know how I can do this when I don't have restriction $\forall_i x_i \in \left\{0,1,2\right\}$:
$$ ooooooooooooo  \text{ n+(k-1) = 7 + (7-1) = 13 balls }$$
$$ oo||o|oo|o|o|  \text{ k-1 = 6 balls I replace with sticks }$$
and I have $$ 2 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 7 $$
I can do this in $$ \binom{n+k-1}{k} = \binom{13}{7} $$ ways. But how to deal with additional restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of unique combinations of numbers summed to achieve $7$ in such a way are
$$\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$$
$$\{2,1,1,1,1,1\}$$
$$\{2,2,1,1,1\}$$
$$\{2,2,2,1\}$$
So the total number of solutions is given by 
$$\frac{7!}{7!}+\frac{7!}{5!}+\frac{7!}{3!\cdot2!\cdot2!}+\frac{7!}{3!\cdot3!}=393$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The answer is the coefficient of $x^7$ in $(1 + x + x^2)^7$.

Comment: I know, I get this from generating function.

Comment: So can you compute it?

Comment: Do you mean manual? Chmm, there is a lot of calculus. But what if there will be not $7$ but $77$? Unless you think about some smarter way?

Comment: I was thinking about pattern $(1+x)^n$ but it also doesn't simplify that

Comment: The result for any particular exponent does not have a nice closed form expression. To use your example, for $77$, the answer is $27\cdot 19 \cdot 233 \cdot 675602617$ times a $22$-digit prime.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426).

Comment: But no, I wouldn't want to try to compute a number like $304080296820632548688921809257611271$ by hand.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You want the coefficient of $x^7$ in
$$
(1+x+x^2)^7=\left(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^7=(1-x^3)^7\times (1-x)^{-7}
$$
Now, $(1-x^3)^7$ and $ (1-x)^{-1}$ are the generating functions of two nice series, $a_n$ and $b_n$; can you find them? Once you do, since you want the *convolution* of these two series:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^7 a_kb_{n-k}.
$$
Furthermore, you will find that $a_k$ equals zero unless $k$ is a multiple of $3$, so that the above summation is has only three nonzero terms and is therefore easily computable by hand.

Comment: $b_n = 1 $ because we have $1+x+x^2+x^3...$ and but $a_n$ seems to be finite

Comment: Yes, $a_n$ is finite. $a_{3k}=\binom{7}{k}(-1)^k$, and $a_{3k+1}=a_{3k+2}=0$. But you expanded $(1-x)^{-7}=\frac1{(1-x)^7}$ incorrectly. Use Newton's binomial theorem. @VirtualUser

Answer (score 2):

The "closed form answer" for the number of ways to assign  $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots ,x_k\}$ such that $\forall n : x_n \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^k x_n = k$ is, for odd $k$
$$
F^{-\frac{k}2, -\frac{k-1}2}_1(4)
$$
and for even $k$
$$
F^{-\frac{k-1}2, -\frac{k}2 }_1(4)
$$
These $F^{a,b}_c$ are hypergeometric functions.

This is obtained by letting $n$ be the number of $2$s used and doing 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\left\lfloor{\frac{k}2}\right\rfloor \binom{k}{n}\binom{k-n}{k-2n}
$$
and using the techniques put forth in Concrete Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

From the theory of Generating Functions it's clear the answer boils down to finding the coefficient of $x^7$ in $(1 + x + x^2)^7$,

Write out the equivalent of Pascal's Triangle for the Trinomial Coefficients, or look it up, or write a quick program to generate them (each term is the sum of the three terms, above left, directly above, above right) 
$$1$$
$$1 : 1 : 1$$
$$1: 2: 3: 2: 1$$
$$1: 3: 6: 7: 6: 3: 1$$
$$1: 4: 10: 16: 19: 16: 10: 4: 1$$
$$1: 5: 15: 30: 45: 51: 45: 30: 15: 5: 1$$
$$1: 6: 21: 50: 90: 126: 141: 126: 90: 50: 21: 6: 1$$
$$1: 7: 28: 77: 161: 266: 357: 393: 357: 266: 161: 77: 28: 7: 1 $$
The number sought is the central coefficient in Row 7, the 393.